# "Edit" menu item not present when adding Nutshell.mdf to Linqpad

Tags: linqpad

I'm trying to work through the examples preloaded with LinqPad. Under "C# 5.0 in a Nutshell", "Getting started" it says "If you don't have SQLExpress installed, the connection on the left will display in red and this query will throw an exception". Well, I do have SQL Server Express installed, but the connection is still displayed in red and running the query does throw an exception.

What the tutorial says to do is 'Right-click "Nutshell.mdf" on the left, and choose "Edit"' but when I right-click "Nutshell.mdf" on the left the only menu items I get are "New Query", "Use in current query" (disabled), "Close all connections", "Refresh", "Delete connection", "Rename connection", "Create similar connection..." and "Properties". No "Edit" item.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Properties" item - this will bring up the edit dialog.